# Android Compose Text Can we have two different texts set to the start and to the end of parent using same Text() field?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use just one Text composable and have two different texts displayed to the start of the parent and to the end of the parent. Is there a recommended way of doing it? I was looking at the official documentation for Text composable and I could only find that using "buildAnnotatedString", we can have multiple texts vertically stacked on top of each other with the help of withStyle and lineHeight. But I am trying to do something like this:[Total $40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuToH.png) But "Total" should be all the way to the left and
"$40" should be all the way to the right.

Comment: what's the purpose of having one `Text`? In a `Row` you can achieve this easily with 2. First one with `Modifier.weight(1f)` displaying **Total*** can cover space that is not used by second and second one will display the **$40** at the end of your `Row`.

Comment: If I were to use two "Text", then which one is better the one you suggested or the below one:
Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
@Thracian

Comment: You can use that too or a Box and Modifier.align() on each element or a layout that places first one on start and second one on end of your Composable. It's a matter of preference really. You can have use any option mentioned.

Comment: Awesome!! @Thracian, Thank you so much for your prompt response. I am still pretty new to compose and learning.